# adodb recordcount returning wrong values

Tags: vba, excel, resultset, adodb

I am querying the excel using the below code to get the rows matching a certain condition:

```
For i = 90 To Worksheets("My Sheet").Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row
' This for loop is to iterate through the list of dates in the excel sheet
Value = Worksheets("My Sheet").Range("E" & i).Value - #1/1/1900# + 2
'Using the above line i am converting the date i want to filter the date 
 'into numeric
strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [My another sheet$A3:I" & LastRow & "] WHERE [Date1]< " &
Value & " AND ([somefield] = 'dog' or [somefield] = 'cat')"
    ' Here in the SQL query i am trying to see how many cats and dogs are satisfying with my date criteria
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        With rs
            .ActiveConnection = cn
            .Source = strQuery
            .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
            .CursorLocation = adUseClient
            .LockType = adLockOptimistic
            .Open
        End With


' Executing the select query on excel as database using ADODB api
    If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then        
        Else
            rs.MoveLast        
    End If
 Worksheets("My Sheet").Range("F" & i).Value = rs.RecordCount
 rs.Close
 ' Moving to the next date in the list
Next
```

I have data something like this

1. 01/01/2012      dog         A
2. 02/01/2012      cat         B
3. 03/01/2012      cat         C
4. 04/01/2012      rat         D
5. 05/01/2012      cat         E
6. 06/01/2012      parrot          F

and my list has dates like this

1. 12/31/2010 - Here i have to find how many cats and dogs are
   purchased from the shop with date less than this date
2. 12/31/2011 - Here i have to find how many cats and dogs are
   purchased from the shop with date less than this date

The purpose of the for loop is to iterate through these dates and modifying the select query
This are the values i am receiving from the above code

`32
35
37
44
57
64
71
78
84
86
89
91
91`

But i should get these values 
`32
36
37
47
57
66
73
81
84
89
90
91
91`

I read somewhere like that we should issue the command `rs.movelast` before using the record count property but still it is showing wrong result on some iterations..

Is it because of the loop and i am using the same record set.

The reason i know the count should be is because i just did the same filtering on excel columns and it is showing different count

There is no datatype changing in the columns i.e. each column has same data structure from start to end

Please help me on this.

I hope the question is clear..please let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: I see you have a close vote and I am not surprised, because I cannot make out what you are doing, either. What is the For ... Next loop for? Where does LastRow come from? Is your data in different cases? Are all your dates good? How do you know what the count should be?

Comment: I am sorry.added more details to the question.

Comment: Sorry for all this drama..I just realized that when i am doing the filtering in Excel, I am selecting condition as less than or equal to..but in select equal condition is missing..Thanks everyone..I don't know how to close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It eliminates the loop. Sheet7 has a list of dates and Sheet8 has the data.

```
Sub groupbydate()
    sSQL = "TRANSFORM Count(b.Dates) AS CountOfDates " _
    & "SELECT 'Total' AS Total " _
    & "FROM [Sheet7$] a, [Sheet8$] b " _
    & "WHERE b.Animal In ('cat','dog') " _
    & "AND b.[dates]<=a.[dates] " _
    & "GROUP BY 'Total' " _
    & "PIVOT a.Dates"

    strFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
        & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

    ''Late binding, so no reference is needed

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    cn.Open strCon

    rs.Open sSQL, cn, 3, 3

    For i = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
        Worksheets("Sheet8").Cells(1, 5 + i) = rs.Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next
    Worksheets("Sheet8").Cells(2, 6).CopyFromRecordset rs

    ''Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```